# Getting input of input box

Tags: html, django, input

I have a input box that, when submitted gives a python method a POST (I'm using django). I'd like to have the search term that the user entered so that I can call methods upon it, preferably in string form.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to get the text client side, or server side?

Answer (score 2):

In your view, you can get POST parameters like this:

```
def myview(request):
    p = request.POST['parameter']
    # do something with p
    # return http response
```

Comment: hey- that doesn't work - it's throwing an error key 'parameter' error not found in QueryDict

Comment: Sigh. 'parameter' was an example. Use the name of your input.

Comment: It might be good to use `request.POST.get("parameter")` instead of `request.POST["parameter"]`. The former does not throw an exception if parameter is not given in the form, the latter does. Since it is related to the user input, invalid inputs should not raise `HTTP 500` but handled properly by coder.